# Mysql Cannot add foreign key constraint weird error

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys

My sql to create two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE Classroom (
  building VARCHAR(100),
  room_no SMALLINT,
  capacity SMALLINT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (building, room_no)
);

CREATE TABLE Section (
  course_id SMALLINT,
  sec_id SMALLINT,
  semester TINYINT,
  year TINYINT,
  building VARCHAR(100),
  room_no SMALLINT,
  time_slot_id SMALLINT,
  PRIMARY KEY (course_id, sec_id, semester, year),
  FOREIGN KEY (building) REFERENCES Classroom(building),
  FOREIGN KEY (room_no) REFERENCES Classroom(room_no)
);
```

But this line:

```
FOREIGN KEY (room_no) REFERENCES Classroom(room_no)
```

gives me a `Cannot add foreign key constraint` Error and I have no idea what happended.
I ran this on [sqlfiddle](https://sqlfiddle.com) (mysql 5.6) to build the database schema. May I know why this happened?

Comment: Classroom(room_no) is no key. (Neither pk, nor unique constraint.)

Comment: @jarlh but didn't I have it as primary key in Classroom table?

Comment: No, that pk consists of building and room_no together.

Comment: @jarlh I see... Thanks for the explanation